# How to use group and sum in a same query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of since 250.000 records and i need to structurated a performing query that:

for each product code, it export a sum of quantities sold daily.

An example:

[image]

Which query could produce this result?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck? This community expects you to demonstrate a minimal research effort.

Comment: Join the two tables on the `id_order` column, then use `SUM(product_quantity)` and `GROUP BY date, id_product`

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data or results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.Date, od.id_product, SUM(product_quantity) as `total quantity`
FROM `Order` o
INNER JOIN Order_Detail od ON od.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.Date, od.id_product
ORDER BY o.Date, od.id_product
```